# Does "mobile phone" grammatically fit into "Almost everyone has mobile phone now"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

> Almost everyone has **mobile phone** now.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? If not, how do I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

**(I)** Nouns in English are divided into two groups:

- *Countable* nouns (book, cat, student, etc.)
- *Uncountable* nouns (water, air, information, etc.)

**(II)** Countable nouns are always used with an article before them. There are two possible situations:

- The article "a" or "an" is used for *indefinite countable* nouns.
- The article "the" is used for *definite countable* nouns.

**EXAMPLE**:

1. There is **a** child in the garden. (We do not know who this child
   is!)
2. **The** child is playing with a ball.

The first sentence informs us about a child who is in the garden. But we do not know any other information about this child. The second sentence informs us about a child too. However, after the first sentence, we know that this child is the child that was mentioned in the first sentence. That is; the child playing with a ball is the child in the garden. There might be other children around, for example another child driving a bicycle in the street, but the article **"the"** makes sure that the speaker is referring to the child mentioned in the first sentence. This extra information is provided with the use of the article **"the"**.

**(III)** Since *"mobile phone"* is a *countable indefinite* noun in your sentence, it must be preceded with the article **"a"**.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing an article:

> Almost everyone has **a** mobile phone now.

Comment: Please take the time to explain why.